# How to mock some nosql backends for integration testing

Tags: scala, redis, integration-testing, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In my project (Scala) I am using a lot of NoSQL systems like Kafka, Zookeeper and Redis. What we do currently for integration testing is starting all such systems as embedded processes within SBT. So now we have for example our app deployed in embedded jetty with embedded kafka/zookeeper/redis-cluster started.

The issue with this solution is that we have to manage this 'zoo' of JVM/Linux processes and it is not simple to do locally and on our CI environment.

What I need is some *lightweight* Kafka/Redis implementation, that I can use for integration testing without starting/forking processes at runtime.

Is there a better approach or ready implementations?

Comment: More lightweight than Redis?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer yes, something like redis mock in memory that I can use in my tests instead of real redis process. Any ideas?